# Замена части строки

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Необходимо заменить часть строки длиной более 70 символов (включая пробелы) например на "...".
Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx

Comment: Ну, да, Replace. Если часто, то еще и через StringBuilder. Если совсем наворочено, то регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str = "ваша_строка12345";
str str.Replace("ваша_строка", "...");
```

Answer (score 10):

Вставлю свои несколько копеек.  Replace и Substring для string - это, конечно, очень хорошо. Но проблема этого кода состоит в том, что строки в C# неизменяемы (unsafe не в счет) - то есть при кажой операции со строкой она создается заново. Так вот, скажем, требования к памяти в случае последовательной конкатенации возрастают в арифметической прогрессии, а это уже плохо. Если вы, скажем, задумаете проворачивать всяческие операции со строками (да еще и не с самыми маленькими, судя по вашему вопросу), то использовать для этих целей string не слишком оптимально. Тут как раз подойдет специально для этих целей созданный StringBuilder. У которого, кстати, также есть Replace в количестве аж четырех перегрузок

Comment: да не так часто это будет использоваться) нужно было просто чтобы название не превышало определенную длину, а лишнее заменялось троеточием)

Comment: Тогда не понимаю логику принятия Вами ответа :-)

Comment: @blackoverdose, костыль явно делаете. Где этот текст выводиться будет?

Comment: Есть несколько ListBox`ов над каждым из которых висит Label, в который суется нужный текст...
в общем каждый листбокс это список тем или разделов, выбрав раздел появляется другой листбокс с темами, над ним написано название раздела... наверно глупо объяснил)

Comment: Нормально объяснили, но делаете неправильно.

Вместо Label используйте TextBlock. У него есть свойство TextTrimming и значение CharacterEllipsis, которое автоматом сделает многоточие... И не придётся пытаться определить, а сколько же символов надо заменять (что, кстати, не самая простая задача (знаю, делал))

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx

Comment: спасибо попробую) а зачем определять сколько символов заменять?
я просто возьму часть строки что после нужного мне символа:

    string tt = tm.Substring(36);
    
и заменю ее на троеточие)

Comment: @blackoverdose, проблемы начнутся как только изменится кегль/стиль шрифта, размеры лабельки/окна и фаза Луны до кучи

Comment: а если я их жестко прописал? размер окна не меняется

Comment: Когда делается для себя, то в целом не важно, а вот когда есть заказчик, все гораздо веселее :-) Я не говорю, что Вам надо перестать самостоятельно Replace делать, но правильный способ все-таки возьмите на заметку

Comment: @blackoverdose, 
>"спасибо попробую) а зачем определять сколько символов заменять? я просто возьму часть строки что после нужного мне символа:"

А зачем так? Почему просто не взять первые 36 символов от строки, зачем заменять?

Comment: Это, конечно, классно, на вы и вправду думаете, что 70 символов 'i' занимают столько же места по горизонтали, что и 70 символов 'Ж'?

Comment: Если систем фонт какой нить поставить - то да :-)

Comment: @Чад: а если этого фонта у юзера не окажется, и он заменится на фонт по умолчанию? Костыли есть костыли, и без крайней на то необходимости городить их не нужно. А в данном случае такой необходимости не видно.

Не говоря уже о локализации: китайские иероглифы, к примеру, ещё шире, чем 'Ж'. Системный фонт тут не поможет, т.к. он (часто) не-Unicode.

Comment: Да я с Вами согласен что если "молотком, но по уму" надо ещё задействовать measureText. Шрифт Terminal есть в винде всегда.

Answer (score 4):

```
var crunchedString = bigString.Length > (70-3) ? bigString.SubString(0,70-3)+"..." : bigString
```